# LINQ Skip still enumerates skipped items

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In the following test:

```
int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Func<int, int> boom = x => { Console.WriteLine(x); return x; };
var res = data.Select(boom).Skip(3).Take(4).ToList();
Console.WriteLine();
res.Select(boom).ToList();
```

The result is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

4
5
6
7
```

Essentially, I observed that in this example, `Skip()` and `Take()` work well, `Skip()` is not as lazy as Take(). It seems that `Skip()` still enumerates the items skipped, even though it does not return them.

The same applies if I do `Take()` first. My best guess is that it needs to enumerate at least the first skip or take, in order to see where to go with the next one.

Why does it do this?

Comment: Well, `Skip(n)` works by asking for the next element, `n` times. The next element comes from your select. Some collections might make sense to 'jump ahead', but not all. What if the collection was generated by a custom enumerator?

Comment: `Skip` is not increasing index by `n` or something like this. `Skip` is just telling enumerator "give a next item" `n` times without storing these values in a result array.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, i think your explanation makes the most sense. @Rob, indeed, a custom enumerator that actually never inspects the lazy item would be better here. I think that's how Skip/Take should work. But the iterator in `Where()` is even worse.

Comment: @ericosg I wasn't advocating a custom enumerator for skip, I was saying that it's *not possible* for skip to directly jump `n` items ahead, because of things like custom enumerators.

Comment: @ericosg As for `Where`, it should be clearer why it needs to iterate each item. What if it were `Where(a => a == 1)` and `boom` was yielding random numbers between `1-5`? `Where` would *have* to iterate each item to get all the ones with the value of `1`.

Comment: @Rob, yeah that's where a `Where()` overload with only an iterator index would be handy.

Comment: @ericosg Sorry, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Rob, if there was a `Where` which had a 3rd overload, (i.e. `Where<T>(Func<int, bool> predicate)` where `int` is the element source index, it would be useful in my case.

Comment: @ericosg You can write it yourself as an extension :) - Should essentially just be `public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source>, Func<T, bool> predicate, int index) { return source.Skip(index).Where(predicate); }` - and then use it just like any other LINQ method

Comment: **Do not make projections that have side effects**. Projections exist to *produce a result*, not a side effect. The behaviour of a projection with a side effect can be very bizarre indeed, as you have discovered.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Skip()` and `Take()` both operate on `IEnumerable<>`.

`IEnumerable<>` does not support skipping ahead -- it can only give you one item at a time. With this in mind, you can think of the `Skip()` more as a filter -- it still touches all the items in the source sequence, but it filters out however many you tell it to. And importantly, it filters them out from getting to whatever is next, not for whatever is in front of it.

So, by doing this:

```
data.Select(boom).Skip(3)
```

You are performing `boom()` on each item *before* they get to the `Skip()` filter.

If you instead changed it to this, it would filter prior to the `Select` and you would call `boom()` on only the remaining items:

```
data.Skip(3).Take(4).Select(boom)
```

Comment: I guess it's still better than `Where`, since that iterates through all 10 to get the iterator. i.e. `var res = data.Select(boom).Where((x,i) => i >= 3 && i < 7).ToList();` vs `var res = data.Where((x,i) => i >= 3 && i < 7).Select(boom).ToList();`

Comment: There should be virtually no difference between `Where()` and `Skip()` in terms of items touched. There will be a marked difference between `Where()` and `Take()`, though..

Comment: indeed that's the case.

Answer (score 5):

If you decompile `Enumerable`, you will see the following implementation of `Skip`:

```
while (count > 0 && e.MoveNext())
  --count;
```

and the following implementation of `Take`:

```
foreach (TSource source1 in source)
{
  yield return source1;
  if (--count == 0) break;
}
```

So, both of these LINQ methods actually enumerate through these items. The difference is whether an enumerated item will be placed in the resulting collection or not. That's how `IEnumerable` does work.

Comment: Your decompiler found a really verbose way to express `if (--count == 0) break;`

Comment: Implementation of Skip method is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,90ccdbd47b57182e,references) - referencesource.

Comment: @CoryNelson Thanks for improving :) I have edited my answer. That's how Resharper does work.

Answer (score 2):

They both iterate the collection. And then turnout with the final collection. Its just like a simple `for loop` having a `if else` condition in it.

Moreover you're selecting it first using `boom`, it prints the item of collection.

By this example you can not tell if `skip()` or `take()` iterates the whole collection or not but the matter of fact, they do.

Answer (score 1):

assuming i have understood your question correctly.

the boom func executes before the skip operation.

try to select data after skip and take , you will get the exact.

Comment: Yes indeed, I know that if I Skip/Take after my select it works as expected, but my ponder is as to why the visa-versa doesn't.

Comment: coming for your  question,  while performing the result for  var res = data.Select(boom).Skip(3).Take(4).ToList(); the boom function executed seven times totally ( 3 for skip and 4 for take) so it prints. and the final result from the filtered array.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour maybe will be changed in the future, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/4551) in this discussion about a Pull Request that optimizes the behaviour of the Skip method for sources that implement the IList interface.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but think about how `Skip(...)` would be implemented.  Here's one way to do it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Skip<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int count)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (count > 0) count--;
        else yield return item;
    }
}
```

Notice that the whole `list` argument is enumerated even though only a subset is returned.